# Convert Byte to Int in SSAS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx

I have a column in SSAS with data type system.byte.

My question for you.

What syntax do I need to use to convert the value from byte to int in Named Calculation in SSAS?

Of course, it would be also great to know how to convert from byte to string.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you use in the data source view for calculated columns is that of the relational data source, i. e. if you are using a SQL Server relational database as the source then it would be Transact SQL syntax, if you use an Oracle database then you should use the Oracle SQL syntax, etc.

In most relational database systems, the type conversion syntax is

```
CAST(<expression> as <target data type>)
```

Some relational database systems support other conversion methods as well, but the above is the standard one supported more or less by all relational databases.